# How to get NReco.PdfGenerator.LT working with Linux binaries?

Tags: linux, .net-core

I'm using [NReco.PdfGenerator.LT](https://www.nrecosite.com/pdf_generator_net.aspx) to create a PDF document from a HTML page. This works fine on windows if I just point it at the wkhtmltopdf.exe executable, but this does not have the same effect on Linux.

```
HtmlToPdfConverter cvt = new HtmlToPdfConverter();

cvt.PdfToolPath = GetPdfToolPath();
// Windows: <current-dir>\wkhtmltopdf\win32\bin
// Linux: <current-dir>/wkhtmltopdf/linux/bin

cvt.WkHtmlToPdfExeName = GetPdfToolName();
// Windows: wkhtmltopdf.exe
// Linux: wkhtmltopdf
```

I just get this error:

> Cannot generate PDF: Permission denied

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Possible reasons of this error:

- linux user who starts .net core program has no permissions to run "wkhtmltopdf". Also ensure that "wkhtmltopdf" file is marked as "executable" (x).
- sometimes temp folder returned by Path.GetTempPath() is not accessible; another location for temp files may be specified with `HtmlToPdfConverter.TempFilesPath` property

Comment: Thank you Vitaliy. `chmod -x wkhtmltopdf` fixed the issue. All is well with the world once again.

Comment: Will this run azure linux?